# Why is cold water black after water heater install?

Tags: water, installation, heater

Brother in law installed a new water heater today and now all cold water taps and toilets have black smelly water. They ran taps and hoses to try to clear but day later and has not cleared up.

Comment: Some photos of the equipment and water may help

Comment: New water heater really shouldn't have affected cold water (never mind all cold water) unless (1) he SERIOUSLY botched things, or (b) the two are unrelated and you just happen to be getting bad water at the same time.

Comment: What's your water source -- well, city water, other?

Comment: Perhaps turned off whatever was treating your black sulfur problem when shutting off the water to work on the water heater and then turned the water back on without turning on the treatment system, or leaving it bypassed.

Comment: Old galvanized pipes, when disturbed, can produce strange water. It seems odd that it continues past a day.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have hydronic heating (radiators or floor heating)?

Is seems he somehow routed the heating water to the potable water. That means you don't have potable water at the tap and your heating pipes corrode fast, as they aren't made for constant fresh water

Answer (score 0):

**Brother in law installed**

after reading your title then the first 4 words, yeah sounds like mistake was made and the cold water feed to the hot water heater is coming from the boiler circuit.